An entire function such that $|\operatorname{Re}f(z)|>0.001 |\operatorname{Im}f(z)|$ must be constant.
I was going over some previous qualifying exams to prepare for my own, and came across the following problem:

Problem. Suppose that $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is entire and has the property that for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$,
$$|\operatorname{Re} f(z)|>0.001 |\operatorname{Im} f(z)|. $$
Show that $f$ is constant.

My first thought would be to use the following identities:
$$
   |e^{f(z)}|=e^{\operatorname{Re}f(z)}, \qquad |e^{-if(z)}|=e^{\operatorname{Im}f(z)}
$$
to say something along the lines of
$$
e^{1000f(z)+if(z)}=e^{1000\operatorname{Re} f(z)-\operatorname{Im} f(z)}
$$
and perhaps use some version of the inequality above to show that $e^{1000f(z)+if(z)}$ is bounded, hence constant by Liouville's Theorem. A common trick would then show that $(1000+i)f(z)$ and therefore $f(z)$ is constant. I cannot however, figure out how to fill in these steps since the inequality we are given has absolute value terms around the real and imaginary parts. Does anyone know how to proceed?

I don't know if it's what you want, but little Picard gives the result easily.

Ah! You are right. From the way the question was phrased, I feel like there is a more elementary solution though.

For an elementary proof just observe that the given inequality fails on $f^{-1}(D(ni,1))$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Now apply Liouville's Theorem to $\frac  1 {f-ni}$.

When you say that the given inequality fails on $f^{-1}(D(ni,1))$, for $n$ sufficiently large, I am a bit confused. Wouldn't this be empty if the property fails?

Yes, I am saying that $f^{-1}(D(ni,1))$ is empty for $n$ sufficiently large and this  means that $|f(z)-ni|\ge 1$ for all $z$ making $\frac 1 {f-ni}$ bounded. . @martianpolarbear

Yes, now I see. Thank you!

You can more generally show that the range of a nonconstant entire function $f(z)$ is dense. Suppose the range of $f$ doesn't intersect an open disk $D(w_0, r)$. Then ${\displaystyle \frac{1}{f(z) - w_0}}$ satisfies ${\displaystyle \bigg|\frac{1}{f(z) - w_0}\bigg| \leq \frac{1}{r}}$ for all $z$. So by Liouville's Theorem, ${\displaystyle \frac{1}{f(z) - w_0}}$ is a constant $C$. Then $f(z) = \frac{1}{C} + w_0$ for all $z$ and thus is also constant.
